# delete the unwanted strings before and after the string in xml file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

xml file  content

```
<distributionChannels><distributionChannel type="Wap" id="1"><contentChannelRefs>
<contentChannelRef id="2"><categories><category 
link="http://images/11.gif" id="1"><names><name lang="de">Top Downloads</name><name
lang="ww">Tops</name></names></category></categories></contentChannelRef>
</contentChannelRefs></distributionChannel>  
</distributionChannels>
```

how do i delete the unwanted content which i am reading from an xml file and the output should look as shown below:

```
<category link="http://images/11.gif" id="1"><names><name lang="de">Top Downloads</name><name lang="ww">Tops</name></names></category>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reliable solution - use an XML parser. Simple solution is

```
s = s.substring(s.indexOf("<categories>"), s.indexOf("</categories>") + 13);
```

if you want to read categories one by one use regex

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<category.*?>.*?</category>").matcher(xml);
    for(int i = 0; m.find(); i++) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

Comment: thanks dorofeev, if i have got multiple <category> in the same string how do i resolve that ...

Comment: thank you, i mean i want to extract is only <category> , lets say if i have 100 of them , i am writing 50 to 1st file and next 50 to 2nd file.

Comment: ok, try the new version, note that it can easily extract attr value and tag content with a little fix

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching with XML is not recommended. Use a parser to get your nodes and the manage them accordingly. If you are interested in printing them I have included code to print the nodes.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,
        IOException, XPathExpressionException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(s)));

    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr
            = xpath.compile("//categories//category");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    //This is where you are printing things. You can handle differently if
    //you would like.
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodeToString(nodes.item(i)));
    }
}

private static String nodeToString(Node node) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    try {
        Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        t.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(sw));
    } catch (TransformerException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sw.toString();
}
```